# Have someone install "IITB Simplecpp in mac"?

Tags: c++, shell, c++11

I am trying to install simplecpp from this website "https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~ranade/simplecpp/"
I am following the mac version.
but when I try to cp file "/usr/include/xlocale.h ./" it gives an error "cp: /usr/include/xlocale.h: No such file or directory"
Please, someone, install and tells me if I am doing wrong or there is an error with the commands given in the website.

Answer (score 0):

Run `locate xlocale.h` to find where that file exists on your machine, and copy it from one of those locations.  For example on some Macs it is in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/usr/include/xlocale.h` if you have XCode and its "Command Line Tools" installed.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have xlocale.h file but I am not able to copy to "usr/include" folder because include folder does not exist

Comment: You don't really need to copy it, you just need to add a `-I` rule for the directory where that file exists when you compile your code.  That way the compiler will find the header file where it already exists.

Comment: John thanks for replying to me again I am a noob and I am a student.                
Install XQuartz http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/
Run Terminal and from it give the command xcode-select --install
You may also have to execute the following from the terminal.
cd /opt/X11/include/X11
sudo mv xlocale.h xlocale.h.bak
sudo cp /usr/include/xlocale.h ./
Download simplecpp.tar
Move simplecpp.tar to the folder of your choice and untar it.
From the terminal go into the simplecpp directory which you extracted and run ./configure.sh .                i am following these steps.